# Trying to get Tic Tac Toe board to reset

Tags: javascript

This is my code for the program, the reset function is called reset. Everything else is working perfectly except for this part. Thank you to anyone who responds. I've been working on this forever now.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <style>
            .tictac
            {
                background:purple;
                border:#999 10px groove;
                width:180px;
                height:180px;
                font-size:150px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            // create a variable for if the game is over, initialize it to false

            var gameOver = false;

            // create a variable for the current player, initialize it to 'O' or 'X'
            // based on who will go first


            if(confirm("X goes first?"))  //Can't figure out how to do Yes or No alert box
            { 
                var player = 'X';
            }
            else
            { 
                var player = 'O';
            } 


            // create an array for the squares using the regular methodology

            var squares = new Array();
                squares[0] = 0;
                squares[1] = 1;
                squares[2] = 2;
                squares[3] = 3;
                squares[4] = 4;
                squares[5] = 5;
                squares[6] = 6;
                squares[7] = 7;
                squares[8] = 8;

            // create a 2-d array of the win combinations, the data is as follows:
            /*
                0, 1, 2
                3, 4, 5
                6, 7, 8
                0, 3, 6
                1, 4, 7
                2, 5, 8
                0, 4, 8
                2, 4, 6

            */

            var winCombinations = [
                [0, 1, 2],
                [3, 4, 5],
                [6, 7, 8],
                [0, 3, 6],
                [1, 4, 7],
                [2, 5, 8],
                [0, 4, 8],
                [2, 4, 6]
            ];

            // declare function named reset with no parameters

            function reset()
            {
                // write a for loop starting at index 1 instead of the 
                // usual 0, that loops through all 9 positions

                var i;
                for (var i = 1; i < squares + 1; i++)
                {
                    // create a variable to relate to each HTML button,
                    // set it equal to explicit text "sqr" concatenated
                    // with the looping variable of the for loop

                    var htmlButton = "sqr" + i;

                    // update the associated HTML element with the id
                    // equal to the variable created above, set it equal
                    // to and explicit empty string

                    htmlButton = "";

                }                   

                // reset the global variable for the squares to an 
                // empty array using the literal methodology

                squares = [];

                // reset the global variable for the game being over
                // setting it equal to false

                gameOver = false;

            }

            // declare function named squareClick with one parameter called square

            function squareClick(square)
            {
                // create a variable that is set equal to the HTML element
                // with the id of square (i.e. the parameter) and retrieve its value
                //

                var idElement = document.getElementById(square).value;

                // this will be used down below as the id to update the HTML element

                // create a variable that is set equal to the JavaScript method call
                // parseInt() passing as an argument square.substring(3, 4), 
                // subtract one from the result of the parseInt method call
                // 

                var parseSquare = ((parseInt(square.substring(3, 4))) - 1);

                // this will represent the index of the array of squares where
                // the user clicked

                // write an if statement that evaluates if the variable
                // value is equal to explicit string ""

                if(idElement === "")  
                {
                    // update the HTML element using the parameter square as
                    // the id, setting its value equal to the global variable
                    // player

                    document.getElementById(square).value = player;

                    // in array of the squares update element stored at
                    // the index retrieved above to the global variable
                    // player

                    squares[parseSquare] = player;

                }

                // call the function checkForWinner passing as an argument
                // the explicit value 'X'

                checkForWinner('X');

                // call the function checkForWinner passing as an argument
                // the explicit value 'O'

                checkForWinner('O');

                // change the player
                // write an if statement that checks if the player variable
                // is equal to O, if true, set player to X

                if(player == 'O')
                    player = 'X';

                // write the else leg that switches player from X to O

                else
                    player = 'O';

            }

            // declare function playAgain with no parameters

            function playAgain()
            {
                // create a variable that stores the response to a
                // confirm dialog box with text "Play again?"

                var response = confirm("Play again?");

                // write an if statement that evaluates the user's response
                // from above compared to true

                if (response == true) 
                {
                    // call function reset

                    reset();

                }
                // write the else leg

                else
                {
                    // display an alert dialog box that thanks the user
                    // for playing

                    alert("Thanks you for playing!");

                }
            }

            // declare function checkForWinner with one parameter called value

            function checkForWinner(value)
            {   

                // write for loop, start at index 0, loop while
                // the index less than the length of the array
                // winCombinations

                for(var i = 0; i < winCombinations.length; i++)
                {
                    // write an if statement that evaluates
                    // the squares array [] where the index is
                    // array winCombinations[][], with the first index
                    // being the looping variable and the second index 
                    // being value 0, 1, or 2, checking if it is 
                    // equal to the value parameter;
                    // this if statement should be 
                    // three statements using the logical and &&
                    // e.g. squares[windCombinations[][]]  == value &&

                    if(squares[winCombinations[i][0]] == value && squares[winCombinations[i][1]] == value && squares[winCombinations[i][2]] == value)
                    {
                        // display an alert dialog box stating which
                        // player won

                        alert(value + " " + "won");

                        // set the variable gameOver equal to true

                        gameOver == true;
                        playAgain();
                    }                   
                }

                // write an if statement checking if gameOver is true

                if(gameOver == true)
                {
                    // call function playAgain

                    playAgain();
                }
                // write the else leg

                else
                {
                    // use the return statement for program control

                    return;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr1" name="sqr1" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr1')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr2" name="sqr2" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr2')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr3" name="sqr3" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr3')" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr4" name="sqr4" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr4')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr5" name="sqr5" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr5')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr6" name="sqr6" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr6')" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr7" name="sqr7" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr7')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr8" name="sqr8" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr8')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr9" name="sqr9" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr9')" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OT: a little tic-tac-toe fiddle I did some time ago https://jsfiddle.net/pg6xpyjo/1/

Comment: What exactly, may I ask, is _not_ working in this code? A good question should be more clear and specific in their question.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're telling anything specific to reset. You have a few options:

1) tell the page to reload (my preferred solution: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

2) reset your specific DOM elements

Comment: This solution has been deprecated. The updated code should be: ``window.location.reload()``

Answer (score 1):

Your `reset()` function has a couple errors - you need to iterate in the for loop using `squares.length` instead of `squares`, and you need to select the button elements using `document.getElementByID()` to then clear their value:

```
function reset() {
  //iterate through all sqr buttons and clear their values
  var buttonId;
  for (var i = 1; i < squares.length; i++) {
    buttonId = "sqr" + i;
    document.getElementById(buttonId).value = "";
  }

  //reset squares to empty Array
  squares = [];

  // reset the global variable for the game being over
  gameOver = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the for loop: it says `(var i = 1; i < squares +1; i++)`, but it should say `(var i = 1; i < squares.length + 1; i++)`